# How do I hide and show sidebar using jquery and css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to be able to show the sidebar when a button is pressed but it seems not to be working.

I have a jquery code to toggle between classes when the button is pressed and inside the css, it should hide/show the sidebar

html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <img src="img/MyPicture.png" alt="MyPicture" class="headshot"/>
    <span style="font-weight:bold">MyName</span>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <div>
            <button id="sidebarToggle">Toggle Menu</button>
        </div>
        <h1>My Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>This is the footer</p>
        &copy; 2019 My Profile
    </div>
</div>
```

site.js:

```
var $sidebarAndWrapper = $("#sidebar,#wrapper");

$("#sidebarToggle").click(function () {
    $sidebarAndWrapper.toggleClass("hide-sidebar");
});
```

site.css:

```
#sidebar {
background:#17153e;
color:#c8c5d3;
position:fixed;
height:100%;
width:250px;
overflow:hidden;
left:0;
margin:0;
}

#sidebar.hide-sidebar {
    left: -250px;
}

#wrapper {
margin:0 0 0 250px;
}
    #wrapper.hide-sidebar {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: [Your code works perfectly fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/1dhtzrm2/1/): are you sure that jQuery is loaded (check your browser's network/resources tab in devtools)? Are you sure that the `#sidebarToggle` element is available at runtime?

Comment: Yes, its loaded fine. When I run it and press f12, I can see the "hide-sidebar" being created anytime I press the button. I'm also using Visual Studio, if that could be an issue

Comment: There's really nothing much I can help, since the code you've posted works fine. My guess is that there's something messing with the code you've written, or that your markup is generated dynamically, which means jQuery can't attach the event handlers at runtime since the elements do not exist yet.

Comment: I agree with @Terry

Comment: how do I check if that's the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your works fine for me, check your Jquery link. It seems that it is not loaded properly. I used a cdn down and it is working just check it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>

#sidebar {
background:#17153e;
color:#c8c5d3;
position:fixed;
height:100%;
width:250px;
overflow:hidden;
left:0;
margin:0;
}

#sidebar.hide-sidebar {
    left: -250px;
}

#wrapper {
margin:0 0 0 250px;
}
    #wrapper.hide-sidebar {
    margin-left: 0;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <img src="img/MyPicture.png" alt="MyPicture" class="headshot"/>
        <span style="font-weight:bold">MyName</span>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main">
            <div>
                <button id="sidebarToggle">Toggle Menu</button>
            </div>
            <h1>My Page</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>This is the footer</p>
            &copy; 2019 My Profile
        </div>
    </div>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
 var $sidebarAndWrapper = $("#sidebar,#wrapper");

$("#sidebarToggle").click(function () {
    $sidebarAndWrapper.toggleClass("hide-sidebar");
});
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed my jquery link to yours and it works now